# How ot make ajax call wait for completion before actioning another call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have to work on two networks, one open and one secret.  My dev env is on my open network and prod is on the secret.  In prod, I load the majority of our data via json from another department, which I don't have access to from dev so I use locally saved json files.  This work's fine but it appears that in prod, the files haven't finished loading when my second function tries to run.  I'm looking for a better way to make function BootstrapNews wait until function GetData is fully loaded.

using Jquery 2.1.4

```
$(function () {

    $.getScript("json.js", function(){

        Page();

    });

    function Page()
    {
        var Breaking = ["F10209"]

        $('#loadingmessage').show();  // show the loading message.
        $.ajax({
            url: GetData(),
            success: function () {
                BootstrapNews();
                $('#loadingmessage').hide(); // hide the loading message
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                $('#loadingmessage').hide(); // hide the loading message
            }            
        })

        function GetData() {
            displayContent(
               'BreakingNews',         //Control to receive the Data
               Breaking,               //Array of Categories to read from
               null,                   //Perform an AND query               20,                     //Max number of results to return
               false,                  //Categories that the Query Hit on.
               false,                  //Display the number of articles returned
               "T",                    //Date Range<strong></strong>
               "E",                     //E or F
               false,           //Is this a DataTable,
               true                     //Is this a Marquee
            );
        }

    function BootstrapNews() {
            $(".breaking-news").bootstrapNews({
                newsPerPage: 6,
                autoplay: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                navigation: false,
                direction: 'down',
                newsTickerInterval: 2500,
                onToDo: function () {
                    //console.log(this);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is `displayContent` defined? Note, you do not `return` `displayContent()` call from `GetData()` call.

Comment: Inside JSON.js...

Comment: What does `displayContent()` return?

Comment: It appends data to a UL

Comment: Why do you call `GetData()` at `url` value of `$.ajax()` call? Is `displayContent` defined as a global variable?

Comment: I've never done this before so I've obviously don't it wrong. All I want to do is append the UL in GetData() so that when BootstrapNews runs, it has li to format

Comment: What should `url` be set to at `$.ajax()` call?

Comment: I don't know what that means, I'm not returning an actual url. I just copied this example, it works with a local file but not when call a JSON from another source

Comment: What resource are you trying to request at `$.ajax()` call?

Comment: Again, I'm not sure what you want to know. I need to append a UL with a bunch of LI in GetData and only when that is done, run BootStarNews.  I'm a n00b in Jquery so I don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: `$.ajax()` `url` property expects a valid URL, not an `html` `<ul>` element. You are also not returning a value from `GetData()` call. When you include `return` statement before `displayContent()` within `GetData()`, what does `console.log(GetData())` log at `console`?

Comment: @TimCadieux what you are looking for is a jQuery promise, basically you have to create your own promise variable, then after your ajax call inside of the success callback you can set your jQuery promise to done. Then you can call the second part of the code. Basically something like this https://jsfiddle.net/pdg7ddqt/ Once your promise is ready you can just .resolve it